# To optimise or simplify a complex SELECT by using analytic functions

Tags: oracle, plsql

Given the following data in the table STATEMENT (creation and data insert commands provided below), I wish to extract the value of the field CUMULATEDAMOUNT for the maximum value of STATEMENTNUMBER  corresponding to the maximum value of STATEMENTDATETIME for group of records that have the same ACCOUNTKEY  value as the ACCOUNTKEY value where the RUNID=14547.

SQL> select * from statement order by 2,4;

```
    +------------+----------+---------------+------------------+----------------+------+-----------------+----------+
    |STATEMENTKEY|ACCOUNTKEY|CLASSIFICATION | STATEMENTDATETIME|STATEMENTNUMBER |RUNID |CUMULATEDAMOUNT  |STATUS    |
    +------------+----------+---------------+------------------+----------------+------+-----------------+----------+
    |      111177|    888881|EndOfDay       | 27/11/15         | 199            |14306 |         202,12  |Created   |
    |      111177|    888881|EndOfDay       | 27/11/15         | 192            |14302 |         606,66  |Processed |
    |      111155|    888882|EndOfDay       | 30/11/15         | 301            |14552 |         303,33  |Processed |
    |      111127|    888886|IncIday        | 27/11/15         | 198            |14506 |         707,77  |Processed |
    |      111118|    888888|EndOfDay       | 17/11/15         | 119            |14547 |         808,88  |Processed |
    |      111112|    888888|EndOfDay       | 19/11/15         | 103            |14500 |         909,99  |Processed |
    |      111144|    888888|EndOfDay       | 27/11/15         | 204            |14509 |         505,55  |Processed |
    |      111183|    888888|EndOfDay       | 28/11/15         | 202            |14514 |         404,44  |Processed |
    |      111104|    888888|EndOfDay       | 29/11/15         | 201            |14513 |         101,11  |Processed |
    |      111194|    888888|EndOfDay       | 29/11/15         | 239            |14813 |         102,22  |Processed |
    +------------+----------+---------------+------------------+----------------+------+-----------------+----------+
    10 ligne(s) selectionnee(s).
```

So ACCOUNTKEY=888888 for RUNID=14547, this yields 6 records

SQL> select * from statement where ACCOUNTKEY=888888 order by 2,4;

```
    +------------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+------+---------------+---------+
    |STATEMENTKEY|ACCOUNTKEY| CLASSIFICATION  |  STATEMENTDATETIME |  STATEMENTNUMBER  | RUNID|CUMULATEDAMOUNT|STATUS   |
    |------------|----------|-----------------|--------------------|-------------------+------+---------------+---------|
    |      111118|    888888| EndOfDay        |  17/11/15          |  119              | 14547| 808,88        |Processed|
    |      111112|    888888| EndOfDay        |  27/11/15          |  103              | 14500| 909,99        |Processed|
    |      111144|    888888| EndOfDay        |  28/11/15          |  204              | 14509| 505,55        |Processed|
    |      111183|    888888| EndOfDay        |  29/11/15          |  202              | 14514| 404,44        |Processed|
    |      111104|    888888| EndOfDay        |  29/11/15          |  201              | 14513| 101,11        |Processed|
    |      111194|    888888| EndOfDay        |  29/11/15          |  239              | 14813| 102,22        |Processed| 
    +------------+----------+-----------------+--------------------+-------------------+------+---------------+---------+
    6 ligne(s) selectionnee(s).
```

MAX(STATEMENTDATETIME) = 29/11/15 for which MAX(STATEMENTNUMBER) = 239 which gives the desired result : CUMULATEDAMOUNT=102,22

My current SELECT is as follows:

```
 select cumulatedamount from statement STX WHERE STX.statementKey in (
    SELECT distinct st2.statementKey FROM statement st2
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT S2.ACCOUNTKEY           as ACCOUNTKEY,
               S2.CLASSIFICATION       as CLASSIFICATION,
               S2.STATEMENTDATETIME    as STATEMENTDATETIME,
               MAX(S2.STATEMENTNUMBER) as STATEMENTNUMBER
        FROM
        (
          SELECT ACCOUNTKEY,
                 CLASSIFICATION,
                 MAX(STATEMENTDATETIME) AS STATEMENTDATETIME
          FROM STATEMENT st3
          WHERE
            STATUS in ('Processed', 'Created')
          AND EXISTS
          (
            SELECT stCur.statementKey FROM statement stCur
            WHERE stCur.runId=14547
            AND stCur.accountKey = st3.accountKey
          )
          GROUP BY
              ACCOUNTKEY, CLASSIFICATION
        ) S1
        INNER JOIN STATEMENT S2 ON S2.ACCOUNTKEY = S1.ACCOUNTKEY
        AND
            S2.STATEMENTDATETIME=S1.STATEMENTDATETIME
        AND
            S2.STATUS in ('Processed', 'Created')
        AND
          S1.CLASSIFICATION =S2.CLASSIFICATION
        GROUP BY S2.ACCOUNTKEY,S2.CLASSIFICATION,S2.STATEMENTDATETIME
    ) v
    ON
    (
        st2.accountKey = v.accountKey
      and
        st2.classification = v.classification
      and
        st2.STATEMENTDATETIME=v.STATEMENTDATETIME
      and
        st2.STATEMENTNUMBER=v.STATEMENTNUMBER
      and
        st2.status in ('Processed', 'Created')
    )
    WHERE
        st2.accountKey = STX.accountKey
    AND
        st2.classification = STX.classification ) AND STX.classification in ('EndOfDay','IncIday');
```

To create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE STATEMENT
(
 STATEMENTLEY NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
 ACCOUNTKEY  NUMBER(38),
 CLASSIFICATION VARCHAR2(30),
 STATEMENTDATETIME DATE NOT NULL ,
 STATEMENTNUMBER VARCHAR2(35),
 RUNID NUMBER(38),
 CUMULATEDAMOUNT NUMBER(38,5),
 STATUS VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

Insert the data:

```
insert into statement (statementkey,accountkey,classification,statementdatetime,statementnumber,runid,cumulatedamount,status)values (111104,888888,'EndOfDay',to_date('29-11-2015 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),201,14513,101.11,'Processed');
insert into statement (statementkey,accountkey,classification,statementdatetime,statementnumber,runid,cumulatedamount,status)values (111194,888888,'EndOfDay',to_date('29-11-2015 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),239,14813,102.22,'Processed');
insert into statement (statementkey,accountkey,classification,statementdatetime,statementnumber,runid,cumulatedamount,status)values (111177,888881,'EndOfDay',to_date('27-11-2015 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),199,14306,202.12,'Created');
insert into statement (statementkey,accountkey,classification,statementdatetime,statementnumber,runid,cumulatedamount,status)values (111155,888882,'EndOfDay',to_date('30-11-2015 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),301,14552,303.33,'Processed');
insert into statement (statementkey,accountkey,classification,statementdatetime,statementnumber,runid,cumulatedamount,status)values (111183,888888,'EndOfDay',to_date('28-11-2015 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),202,14514,404.44,'Processed');
insert into statement (statementkey,accountkey,classification,statementdatetime,statementnumber,runid,cumulatedamount,status)values (111144,888888,'EndOfDay',to_date('27-11-2015 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),204,14509,505.55,'Processed');
insert into statement (statementkey,accountkey,classification,statementdatetime,statementnumber,runid,cumulatedamount,status)values (111177,888881,'EndOfDay',to_date('27-11-2015 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),192,14302,606.66,'Processed');
insert into statement (statementkey,accountkey,classification,statementdatetime,statementnumber,runid,cumulatedamount,status)values (111127,888886,'IncIday',to_date('27-11-2015 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),198,14506,707.77,'Processed');
insert into statement (statementkey,accountkey,classification,statementdatetime,statementnumber,runid,cumulatedamount,status)values (111118,888888,'EndOfDay',to_date('17-11-2015 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),119,14547,808.88,'Processed');
insert into statement (statementkey,accountkey,classification,statementdatetime,statementnumber,runid,cumulatedamount,status)values (111112,888888,'EndOfDay',to_date('19-11-2015 11:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),103,14500,909.99,'Processed');
commit;
```

I would like to simplify the above SELECT by using analytic functions, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
         FROM STATEMENT
         WHERE ACCOUNTKEY = (SELECT ACCOUNTKEY FROM STATEMENT WHERE RUNID = 14547)
         ORDER BY STATEMENTDATETIME DESC,  STATEMENTNUMBER DESC
       )
   WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

or with the analytic function rather than rownum:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT s.*
              ,row_number() OVER(ORDER BY STATEMENTDATETIME DESC, STATEMENTNUMBER DESC) rn
         FROM STATEMENT s
         WHERE ACCOUNTKEY = (SELECT ACCOUNTKEY FROM STATEMENT WHERE RUNID = 14547)
       )
   WHERE rn = 1
```

Replace the `*`s with `CUMULATEDAMOUNT`.

And add other filter criteria `STATUS in ('Processed', 'Created')` accordingly...

Comment: I have upvoted it. what is the use of `ORDER BY STATEMENTDATETIME DESC,  STATEMENTNUMBER DESC`in the inner sub-query of second query above

Comment: In the second query, it is only needed in the `OVER` clause, not on the subquery itself. It remained on the subquery because I cut and paste from the first query, which does require the `ORDER BY` on the subquery so that `ROWNUM = 1` on the wrapper hits the correct record.  I'll update the second query.

Answer (score 1):

Please below one using the `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY .. ORDER BY ..)`

```
SELECT CUMULATEDAMOUNT
FROM (
  SELECT CUMULATEDAMOUNT
    , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY STATEMENTDATETIME DESC, STATEMENTNUMBER DESC) RNK
  FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM STATEMENT
    WHERE ACCOUNTKEY IN (
        SELECT ACCOUNTKEY 
          FROM STATEMENT
        WHERE RUNID = 14547
      )
  )
) WHERE RNK = 1
```